# Create SQL column relative to another

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I have a column with different values :

```
1 
2 
4 
8
```

I want to create a new column in the same table based on these values.

For example, if the value is `1 or 4`, I want to display the corresponding line in `OK` and `NOT OK` for the rest.

Like:

```
1 OK 
2 NOT OK 
4 OK 
8 NOT OK
```

I think we should use an `if` condition, but how to create at same time with the column values ​​in the table?

Comment: if 1 and 4 are always ok and 2 and 8 are always not ok why not create a new table for this and join them on this value? what happens if 5 occurs?

Comment: @Yakyb He told 'not ok' for rest. That treats 5 as well, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use **[Case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)** statement.

```
SELECT 
Case when id in (1,4) Then 'Ok' Else 'Not Ok' End as Myfield
FROM  MyTable
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c37b/3)**

Answer (score 1):

**Since you say "I want to display" I'll give you some If Snippets**

This is how it works, Simply for ex:

```
SELECT IF(field= '1', 'OK', 'NOT OK') as Myfield
FROM  MyTable
```

or

```
SELECT IF(field= '1', 'OK', IF(field= '4', 'OK', 'NOT OK')) as Myfield
FROM  MyTable

;So here the result will be `OK` if there is any 1, 4 or else `NOT OK`
```

**[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) is MySQL Documentation about If Conditions**

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a **new column in your table** or just in the SELECT output? If you need a new table column, add it and then run an UPDATE query.

```
UPDATE `mytable`
SET `result` = CASE 
   WHEN id in (1,4) THEN 'ok'
   ELSE 'not ok' END;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dd61/1/0)